# Translation of message from Chinese to English

Tags: translation

Can you guys translate this message for me. I used a translator and it's inaccurate. And I want to know who slipped the message inside the book. The grandfather, the girl (who posted the message) or another stranger? Or is the grandfather the stranger? And who owns the book? The girl, the stranger or the grandfather? It's about a story.

Please also give me a clear translation of everything, thank you.

1⃣️又体会到有同桌的喜悦感
2⃣️来自一个陌生人的温暖 （本来将书放在门口老爷爷那里保管下 拿回来的时候老爷爷在书里夹了张祝福纸条  感动至极 ）❤️[image]

Answer (score 3):

1
又体会到有同桌的喜悦感
I felt the joy of sitting at the same table again.
(maybe the boy she is crush on)

2
An old man probably sat by the door.
The girl asked him to keep (take care of) the book for her for a while.

The girl didn't know him before.
The stranger is the old man.

Two people. (I think 1 has nothing to do with 2.)

The old man left the message.

祝你學習進步
I wish you progress in your studies.

天天快樂
Happy every day.

Comment: 1
又体会到有同桌的喜悦感
I felt the joy of sitting at the same table again.
(maybe the boy she is crush on) Why do you think she has a crush on a boy?

Answer (score 0):

The  grandfather is the stranger. the one sitting at the same table owns the book.

Answer (score 0):

The girl is the owner of the book. She sighed that she again has the feeling as if she had a table-mate 同桌 again (implying that anytime she loses or leaves something behind, her considerate table-mate (either male or female, it would be more romantic if it is an opposite sex) would help her to find the lost property).

The paper is slipped in the book by the grandfather, who serves as a security at the gate of the school. Unexpectedly, he not only keeps the book in good condition but also returns the same together with a piece of paper, on which there are words written "Wish you progress in your daily study", and those words move the book owner, who thinks that only a table-mate can write such warm-hearted thing as that and that it is impossible for the old man to write down such words.

So it is a story of surprise or suspense.